# Why am I getting two unsupported opperand types when doing a correlation matrix in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, for-loop, dtype

I am trying to make a correlation matrix from my dataframe with all the variables, here is the loop I created:

```
###########################################
###Coefficient de corrélation de Pearson###
###########################################

from scipy.stats import pearsonr

attribute_list = ["model", "year", "price", "transmission", "mileage", "fuelType", "tax", "mpg", "engineSize"]

correlation_coefficient_matrix = np.zeros((len(attribute_list), len(attribute_list)))
pvalue_matrix = np.zeros((len(attribute_list), len(attribute_list)))

for i in range(len(attribute_list)):

    for j in range(len(attribute_list)):

        if i >= j:

            x = my_data_frame[attribute_list[i]].values
            y = my_data_frame[attribute_list[j]].values

            r1, pvalue = pearsonr(x, y)

        if i == j:

            correlation_coefficient_matrix[i, j] = r1
            pvalue_matrix[i, j] = pvalue

        if i > j:

            correlation_coefficient_matrix[i, j] = r1
            pvalue_matrix[i, j] = pvalue

            correlation_coefficient_matrix[j, i] = r1
            pvalue_matrix[j, i] = pvalue

print("This is the correlation matrix between variables, the variables are:")
print(attribute_list)
print("\n")
print(correlation_coefficient_matrix)
print("\n")
print(pvalue_matrix)
```

Here is the error that appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/utilisateur/Desktop/OUTILS DE PROGRAMMATION POUR LA SCIENCE DES DONNÉES/TP1.py", line 127, in <module>
    r1, value = pearsonr(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\utilisateur\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 3919, in pearsonr
    dtype = type(1.0 + x[0] + y[0])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

Can anyone help me with this? I know it has something to do with the types float and string not converting properly but I'm lost...

Thanks!

Comment: `1.0` is a float.  `x` or `y` must be strings, or since they come from dataframe .values, object dtype arrays containing strings.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your answer, I should convert my x and y variables to strings?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  I think `x` and `y` already contain strings.  `+` for strings is join. `+` for numbers is addition.